# Rendering a multidimensional nested JSON response with DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have a JSON structure for images and every image has some tags in this JSON. The structure is like that:

```
{
 "data":[
  {
     "title":"Image Title",
     "slug":"image-title",
     "file_name":"f57fd83c-3c46-4f5b-95b8-446cca3664b5.jpg",
     "added_at":"2015-09-24",
     "tags":{
        "data":[
           {
              "name":"Some Dummy Tag Name",
              "slug":"some-dummy-tag-name"
           },
           ...
        ]
     },
     "added_by":{
        "data":{
           "email":"john@appleseed.com",
           "first_name":"John",
           "last_name":"Appleseed"
        }
     }
  },
  ...
  ]
}
```

And I'm trying to show this JSON data in DataTables. I've managed to render all of the data except tags. I've used the below code for DataTables options but I can't get the tag's name. It returns [object Object] for each tag in each image. But when I try logging the "data[key].name" on the console, it successfully returns the name. What I'm doing wrong?

```
'columnDefs': [
    ...,
    {
        'targets': 2,
        'data': 'tags.data',
        'render': function(data) {
            return $.each(data, function(key) {
                return data[key].name;
            });
     }
},
...
],
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CAUSE

[`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.

#### SOLUTION

Use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to produce an array of tags and `join(', ')` to produce a comma-separated tag list as a string from the array.

```js
'render': function(data, type, row) {        
    var tags = $.map(data, function(tag, i) {
       return tag.slug;
    });

    return tags.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: It totally makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: But what if i don't want comma separated , Instead i need each one to be new row .

Comment: @HosMercury, you can do `return tags.join('<br>');` instead.

Comment: @HosMercury, then see [child rows example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).